# KafkaListener partition mapping within instance for concurrency > 1

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a simple kafka listener annotated method
and `spring.kafka.listener.concurrency = 5`

My topic has 100 partitions, and there are 5 instances of the application running.
The topic has partition keys set, so the consumer level partition affinity exists.
I would like to understand if its possible for multiple threads of the consumer to receive messages from the same partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; with `concurrency = 5`, each instance has 5 distinct consumers; only one consumer in a group can consume from a partition.

Comment: That makes sense. So if I had a concurrent hashmap in the listener method that was tracking the last processed record for each partition (partition being the key of the entry here), running with concurrency 5 should not make it thread-unsafe, right?

Comment: That is correct.